# How to add dom pdf generated pdf file to ZipArchive using PHP

Tags: php, dompdf, php-ziparchive

I have used dom pdf to create a .pdf file from html text content. At the same time I have to create a zip archive and add that pdf file to zip.

That zip contains more two folders as well. I am stuck while adding DOMPDF generated file to the zip archive. Can anyone provide me a solution for this?

Comment: What steps have you taken to add the PDF? Are you using [PHP's zip support](http://us3.php.net/zip)? Is the PDF going into the root of the zip or does it need to go under one of the existing folders?

Comment: @BrianS Thanks for your reply. I got solution for this before one day. :)

Comment: Good to know. Post your solution as an answer in case anyone is interested in how you solved the problem.

Answer (score 5):

Use this code to make pdf file from html content.

```
$html = "put your html code here";
$dompdf = new DOMPDF();
$dompdf->load_html($html);
$dompdf->set_paper("a4", "portrait");
$dompdf->render();
$output = $dompdf->output();
file_put_contents('Otherfile.pdf', $output);
```

After using render() function use output() function to store pdf file in variable.
And put that content inside new file using file_put_contents(). Then use that file to put inside .zip using following code.

```
$files = 'Otherfile.pdf';
$zipname = 'zipname.zip';
$zip = new ZipArchive;      
$zip->open($zipname, ZipArchive::OVERWRITE);
$zip->addFile($files);

$zip->close();
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='".$zipname."'");
header("Pragma: no-cache"); 
header("Expires: 0");
header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate');
header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($zipname));
```